# boost converter giving less output voltage when comapred to input voltage

Tags: voltage, diodes, boost

boost converter design needed 6 V to 12 V. Can Any one give the data

Comment: What switching frequency did you use when you selected the inductor value?

Comment: You need a much higher frequency (eg 10kHz), you will lose more than 2V across the LED, which won't survive long if you do get more than 9V from the output as it needs to be current limited.

Comment: Also need capacitor across load.

Comment: No blinks? not even after 5 seconds?

Comment: Buy and read Switching Power Supplies A-Z by Sanjaya Maniktala http://www.amazon.com/Switching-Power-Supplies-Z-Second/dp/0123865336/

Comment: Dear Sir, In the circuit which I had presented earlier, I have changed the inductance to 3 mh, 1A and the switching frequency I used 30 kHz. At the output side  I have connected capacitor of 1 uF. The load resistance is 1 k ohm. But I have not changed the 1N4007 diode. With these parameters also , I am unable to step -up the voltage. I applied 10 V as input voltage, the output voltage is coming as 8.5 V. I request you to guide me to solve the above problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your circuit makes no sense, let me count the ways:

You want to boost the input voltage, but that is already considerably more than needed to light the LED.

Switching once every 10 seconds is not going to get you miniscule power transfer.  ½(470 µH)(3 A)<sup>2</sup> = 2.1 mJ, which is the maximum energy the inductor can hold.  That times 0.1 Hz means the boost converter can only transfer at most 210 µW of power.

You seem to have completely ignored inductor saturation.  (3 A)(470 µH)/(9 V) = 160 µS, which is the longest the switch can be on before the inductor saturates.

The only reason this appears to work is because current is flowing directly thru the diode without any boost action.  This is because your load runs from the input voltage or less.  The inductor and diode are actually in the way, reducing the output voltage to a little less than the input voltage.

You have 6 V across the 20 Ω resistor in series with the LED.  That means (6 V)/(20 Ω) = 300 mA is flowing thru the resistor and the LED.  Unless this is a high power LED that can actually take 300 mA, you fried it long ago.  Most typical T1-¾ LEDs, for example, are only rated for 20 mA.

A 1N4xxx diode is totally inappropriate in a switching application like this.

So to fix this circuit, loose the inductor, diode, and switch.  Connect the LED and resistor directly to the voltage source.  This time size the resistor correctly for the current the LED can take.  If, for example, you want to run a 20 mA LED that drops 2.1 V, then 6.9 V will be across the resistor.  (6.9 V)/(20 mA) = 345 Ω, which is the smallest allowable resistance.  The standard value of 360 Ω should work nicely.

The reason you were getting less light when switching is because your circuit was never running as a boost converter in the first place.  Turning on the switch only brought the voltage at the left end of the diode to 0, which powered down the output.

Comment: Dear Sir, kindly provide the information on the specifications of the boost converter that i can implement. list of components i have mentioned in the question, which i have edited today.

Comment: Dear Sir, In the circuit which I had presented earlier, I have changed the inductance to 3 mh, 1A and the switching frequency I used 30 kHz. At the output side  I have connected capacitor of 1 uF. The load resistance is 1 k ohm. But I have not changed the 1N4007 diode. With these parameters also , I am unable to step -up the voltage. I applied 10 V as input voltage, the output voltage is coming as 8.5 V. I request you to guide me to solve the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basic boost converters store energy in the inductor in one half cycle then release it to the load in the 2nd half cycle. Energy stored x cycle frequency = power delivered.

Have you considered what happens to your inductor when you short it to ground via the IRF840 - it has an on resistance of 0.85 ohms so pretty soon after turning the transistor on there is about 11 amps flowing through your inductor.

This is why boost converters switch at a high frequency - the rate that the current increases through an inductor is Vsupply/L i.e. for a supply of 9 volts and an inductance of 470 uH, the current ramps up at over 19,000 amps per second so, even if you used a 1kHz cycle and 0.5 ms for the first half of the cycle, the current will reach 9.6 amps. With 10 kHz it's looking more like 0.96 amps.

0.96 amps implies a stored energy of \$L\cdot I^2\$/2 = 216 uJ and, at an operating frequency of 10 kHz this can be a power transfer of about 2.2 watts.

Comment: Dear Sir, kindly provide the information on the specifications of the boost converter that i can implement. list of components i have mentioned in the question, which i have edited today.

Comment: Dear Sir, kindly provide the information on the specifications of the boost converter that i can implement. list of components i have mentioned in the question, which i have edited today.

Comment: Not really. You have a bunch of components some of which will be OK and others that won't and an array of possible circuit outcomes from those components you can use that make answering your request too much to expect. Plus there's a bunch of other stuff needed to make it work. My advice is go do some research on circuit implementations or buy a chip or a module.

Comment: Dear Sir, I come up with the values for different components as follows, in order to avoid the array of possibilities.                                                                         I have changed the inductance to 3 mh, 1A and the switching frequency I used 30 kHz. At the output side  I have connected capacitor of 1 uF. The load resistance is 1 k ohm. But I have not changed the 1N4007 diode. With these parameters also , I am unable to step -up the voltage. I applied 10 V as input voltage, the output voltage is coming as 8.5 V. I request you to guide me to solve the above problem.

Comment: Listen to me. The question was asked and answered by two people. That's it end of story and trying to solicit a design service is really really bad. You have clearly not done any research or you would not be using the 1N4007 diode. You need to listen more.